# No line break after special character for entire document

Tags: line-breaking

I want "GAD65(+/--)" never to be broken in my entire document. When I put `\mbox{GAD65(+/--)}` it works, but I don´t want to edit each single "GAD65(+/--)". Can I set this for the entire document?

I wrote `\mbox{GAD65(+/--)}` into the .cls file, where the word breaking, orphans and so are defined, but it does´t work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The best strategy is to have `\newcommand{\GAD}{\mbox{GAD65(+/--)}}` in the preamble and to use `\GAD{}` in the document body.

Comment: @egreg why the braces in the newcommand? You don't need them if there aren't arguments, right?

Comment: @Alenanno `\newcommand{\GAD}{...}` and `\newcommand\GAD{...}` are completely equivalent; the former is the syntax used in the manual.

Comment: @egreg I was referring to using `\GAD{}` in the document body. If the value is fixed you could just use `\GAD`... no? Maybe I'm missing something. :D

Comment: @Alenanno Oh! Those braces! Well, TeX would eat a space after `\GAD`, without them.

Comment: @egreg So if you added a space in the newcommand, those wouldn't be needed anymore? Or would it be the same?

Comment: @Alenanno if you add a space to the macro, then you can not follow it by `,` or `.` etc...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah didn't know that. Good to do now.

Comment: @Alenanno it's not an error it just makes `GAD65(+/--) .` with a space before the full stop.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's clear now, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a command and use the `\xspace` command to take care of spaces following that command. In the example below I have added a variant for the second paragraph where I use `\small` for `GAD65` because I believe it looks better to typeset acronyms a little smaller. I'm using `\sloppy` as the unbreakability of GAD65 leads otherwise to overfull lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand\GAD{\mbox{GAD65(+/--)}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \GAD
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam \GAD erat,
sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea \GAD.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus \GAD est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
erat, sed diam \GAD.  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum.  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.

\renewcommand\GAD{\mbox{\small GAD65(+/--)}\xspace}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \GAD
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam \GAD erat,
sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea \GAD.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus \GAD est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
erat, sed diam \GAD.  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum.  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `GAD65($+$/$-$)` would be slightly better, wouldn't it?

Comment: I agree that something like `$\mathrm{GAD}\,65(+/-)$` should be better as it would take advantage of TeX's typography for math but the difference is actually pretty small.

Comment: Indeed, I said “slightly”… :-)